# Como pasar una consulta sql a laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

quisiera que me ayudaran a pasar esta consulta a laravel 7
select Entrada,Precio,
sum( CASE
WHEN Movimiento = 1 THEN Cantidad
WHEN Movimiento = 2 THEN Cantidad * -1
END) As Existencia
FROM int_kardex where Articulo = 7
group by Entrada,Precio order by Entrada